# Port forwarding open but refused to connect

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, minecraft

I'm trying to run my minecraft server and port forward it. The port is 25565 (minecraft default).
I have port forward the port and check with [portchecker.co](https://portchecker.co).

[image]

The server works on my local ip, but when I enter my public ip on to minecraft, it says Can't connect to server.

Please note that I am new to port forwarding

Comment: Some routers do not support [hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning). In short, this means that using the public IP for the network (e.g. `1.2.3.4`) from a computer on that same network will not work, even if people outside your network can otherwise connect to e.g. your Minecraft server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Check that the server is showing as online on [this](https://mcsrvstat.us/) website
- If you're running the server on the same computer that you're trying to connect with, try connecting with 'localhost' or your device's IPv4 number

In my experience, when I've set up the server on the same computer that I'm using to connect to the server and play, my public IP address will not work for me but will work for others, and I can only connect using localhost or my device's IPv4 address.

EDIT: I see you mentioned that you can connect using your local IP but not public. As long as the server is showing online on the website I linked above, others should be able to connect fine.

Comment: Thank you! Turns out it works

Comment: Great! Feel free to mark this as the answer if it helped